# iOS custom framework run time showing Symbol not found:

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, tesseract

I added swifty tesseract to one of my custom framework using pod. Created a pod spec and uploaded it in one location.
Now i created a dummy app and tried to pull my custom framework from that particular location and am getting following run time error

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _$s15SwiftyTesseract10EngineModeO21tesseractLstmCombinedyA2CmFWC

  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/601F5612-4BCB-456D-BCCF-71AC522668D5/DemoApp.app/Frameworks/custom.framework/custom

  Expected in: 
  /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/601F5612-4BCB-456D-BCCF-71AC522668D5/DemoApp.app/Frameworks/SwiftyTesseract.framework/SwiftyTesseract
 
 in 

 /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/601F5612-4BCB-456D-BCCF-71AC522668D5/DemoApp.app/Frameworks/custom.framework/custom

dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
```

Can anyone help me with what is this error ? iam not understanding the issue